# Warnings for Maven liquibase plugin?

Tags: maven-plugin, pom.xml, liquibase, changelog, parent-pom

I am trying to generate changeLog file using the Maven LiquiBase plugin.
This is my pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
<artifactId>myTest</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.35</version>
    </dependency>
```

```
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <propertyFile>src/main/Resources/liquibase-3.3.3-bin/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
        </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generateChangeLog</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

```
 </build>
</project>
```

WARNING 1. I tried running "mvn validate". Since I have the goal liquibase:generateChangeLog binding with validate phase. Shouldn't it generate the changeLog file? Build is successful but I get a warning "LiquiBase skipped due to Maven configuration".

WARNING 2. I tried to use "mvn compile". Since this step is after validate, I get the "skipped liquibase" and a new warning "Using platform encoding  to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!"

What can I do to resolve these warnings?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to an issue with Liquibase 3.3.3 which has been fixed in 3.3.4.